# how to Load the custom attribute with the product listing in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

Load the custom attribute with the product listing in magento 2

Comment: you want to disply custom attribute listing page?

Comment: yes I have create one attribute matriyal and also how to disply product listing page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this way...

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('material')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?>
```

Comment: which location?

Comment: where you want to get this attribute? and add above code

Comment: Load the custom attribute with the product listing?

Comment: yes listing page

Answer (score 0):

Based on Rakesh Donga's answer:

Filepath: `<Vendor>/<Theme>/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml`

inside the  `<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>`